# Pygame Basic calculator

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a basic calculator but the problem I am having is how do I output the text? How do I make it so when I click plus it allows me to add or if I click divide it allows me to divide and shows the output on the yellow part on my screen

[image]

This is what I have right now. You could run it; there is nothing special. ***My question is how could I make the calculator make it so when I click plus and then go and add up numbers it allows me to add or when I click divide it allows me to divide my numbers and show the outputs on the screen?***

```
import pygame,math
pygame.init()

window_height = 500
window_width = 500
window  = pygame.display.set_mode((window_height,window_width))

    # the buttons for the shop MENU
class button():
    def __init__(self, color, x,y,width,height, text=''):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.text = text
        self.over = False

    def draw(self,window,outline=None):
                #Call this method to draw the button on the screen
        if outline:
            pygame.draw.rect(window, outline, (self.x-2,self.y-2,self.width+4,self.height+4),0)
                    
        pygame.draw.rect(window, self.color, (self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height),0)
                
        if self.text != '':
            font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 60)
            text = font.render(self.text, 1, (0,0,0))
            window.blit(text, (self.x + (self.width/2 - text.get_width()/2), self.y + (self.height/2 - text.get_height()/2)))

    def isOver(self, pos):
                #Pos is the mouse position or a tuple of (x,y) coordinates
        if pos[0] > self.x and pos[0] < self.x + self.width:
            if pos[1] > self.y and pos[1] < self.y + self.height:
                return True
                    
        return False

    def playSoundIfMouseIsOver(self, pos, sound):
        if self.isOver(pos):            
            if not self.over:
                beepsound.play()
                self.over = True
        else:
            self.over = False
                    
white = (255,255,255)
# the numbers for the calcaltor
s_1s = button((0,255,0),40,450,30,30, '1')
s_2s = button((0,255,0),40,400,30,30, '2')
s_3s = button((0,255,0),40,350,30,30, '3')
s_4s = button((0,255,0),100,450,30,30, '4')
s_5s = button((0,255,0),100,400,30,30, '5')
s_6s = button((0,255,0),100,350,30,30, '6')
s_7s = button((0,255,0),150,450,30,30, '7')
s_8s = button((0,255,0),150,400,30,30, '8')
s_9s = button((0,255,0),150,350,30,30, '9')
s_0s = button((0,255,0),200,450,30,30, '0')

numbers = [s_1s,s_2s,s_3s,s_4s,s_5s,s_6s,s_7s,s_8s,s_9s,s_0s]

# the symbols!
d_1s = button((0,255,0),260,450,30,30, '+')
d_2s = button((0,255,0),260,400,30,30, '-')
d_3s = button((0,255,0),260,350,30,30, 'x')
d_4s = button((0,255,0),200,400,30,30, '÷')

symbols = [d_1s,d_2s,d_3s,d_4s]

# input tap
inputtap = button((253,100,32),10,280,450,50,"")

# redraw window
def redraw():
    # draw all the numbers
    for button in numbers:
        button.draw(window)

    # the symbols
    for button in symbols:
        button.draw(window)

    inputtap.draw(window)
 
def Symbols():
    
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            
        if d_1s.isOver(pos):
            print("+")

        if d_2s.isOver(pos):
            print("-")

        if d_3s.isOver(pos):
            print("x")

        if d_4s.isOver(pos):
            print("÷")
    

def MOUSEOVERnumbers():
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()          
        if s_1s.isOver(pos):
            print("1")
        if s_2s.isOver(pos):
            print("2")
        if s_3s.isOver(pos):
            print("3")
        if s_4s.isOver(pos):
            print("4")
        if s_5s.isOver(pos):
            print("5")
        if s_6s.isOver(pos):
            print("6")
        if s_7s.isOver(pos):
            print("7")
        if s_8s.isOver(pos):
            print("8")
        if s_9s.isOver(pos):
            print("9")
        if s_0s.isOver(pos):
            print("0")            

# the main loop
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        MOUSEOVERnumbers()

        Symbols()

    redraw()
    pygame.display.update()
pygmae.quit()
```

Comment: First thing you should do, is get numbers input to display on the screen, and create a value based on digits entered.  I ran your program and it didn't even do that.

Comment: You can develop a simple calculator using tkinter

Comment: It is awkward to use pygame to make a calculator. Use Tkinter instead, if you could, it will save you a lot of time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add a `=` button, so every time user clicks it, calculate the user input with python `eval()` function.

As for the user input, you first need to record it globally . Then you can pass user input to the string field of `inputtap = button((253,100,32),10,280,450,50,"")` to show it on the window.

```py
import pygame, math

pygame.init()

window_height = 500
window_width = 600
window  = pygame.display.set_mode((window_height,window_width))

# the buttons for the shop MENU
class button():
    def __init__(self, color, x,y,width,height, text=''):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.text = text
        self.over = False

    def draw(self,window,outline=None):
        #Call this method to draw the button on the screen
        if outline:
            pygame.draw.rect(window, outline, (self.x-2,self.y-2,self.width+4,self.height+4),0)
                    
        pygame.draw.rect(window, self.color, (self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height),0)
                
        if self.text != '':
            font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 60)
            text = font.render(self.text, 1, (0,0,0))
            window.blit(text, (self.x + (self.width/2 - text.get_width()/2), self.y + (self.height/2 - text.get_height()/2)))

    def isOver(self, pos):
        #Pos is the mouse position or a tuple of (x,y) coordinates
        if pos[0] > self.x and pos[0] < self.x + self.width:
            if pos[1] > self.y and pos[1] < self.y + self.height:
                return True
        return False

    def playSoundIfMouseIsOver(self, pos, sound):
        if self.isOver(pos):            
            if not self.over:
                beepsound.play()
                self.over = True
        else:
            self.over = False
                    
white = (255,255,255)
# the numbers for the calcaltor
s_1s = button((0,255,0),40,450,30,30, '1')
s_2s = button((0,255,0),40,400,30,30, '2')
s_3s = button((0,255,0),40,350,30,30, '3')
s_4s = button((0,255,0),100,450,30,30, '4')
s_5s = button((0,255,0),100,400,30,30, '5')
s_6s = button((0,255,0),100,350,30,30, '6')
s_7s = button((0,255,0),150,450,30,30, '7')
s_8s = button((0,255,0),150,400,30,30, '8')
s_9s = button((0,255,0),150,350,30,30, '9')
s_0s = button((0,255,0),200,450,30,30, '0')

numbers = [s_1s,s_2s,s_3s,s_4s,s_5s,s_6s,s_7s,s_8s,s_9s,s_0s]

# the symbols!
d_1s = button((0,255,0),260,450,30,30, '+')
d_2s = button((0,255,0),260,400,30,30, '-')
d_3s = button((0,255,0),260,350,30,30, 'x')
d_4s = button((0,255,0),200,400,30,30, '÷')
d_5s = button((0,255,0),200,350,30,30, '=')
d_6s = button((0,255,0),260,500,30,30, 'C')

symbols = [d_1s,d_2s,d_3s,d_4s,d_5s,d_6s]


# redraw window
def redraw(inputtap):
    # draw all the numbers
    for button in numbers:
        button.draw(window)

    # the symbols
    for button in symbols:
        button.draw(window)

    inputtap.draw(window)

def Symbols():
    global user_input
    global python_input
    global is_finished

    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        try:
            if is_finished or user_input[-1] in ["+", "-", "x", "÷", "="]:
                # User shouldn't type two symbols continuously
                # User shouldn't input any symbols when game finished because there is no number
                return
        except IndexError:
            # User shouldn't input any symbols if there is no number
            return


        if d_1s.isOver(pos):
            print("+")
            user_input += "+"
            python_input += "+"

        if d_2s.isOver(pos):
            print("-")
            user_input += "-"
            python_input += "-"

        if d_3s.isOver(pos):
            print("x")
            user_input += "x"
            python_input += "*"

        if d_4s.isOver(pos):
            print("÷")
            user_input += "÷"
            python_input += "/"

        if d_5s.isOver(pos):
            print("=")
            result = eval(python_input)
            python_input = ""
            user_input += f"={result:.2f}"
            is_finished = True

        if d_6s.isOver(pos):
            print("C")
            python_input = ""
            user_input = ""

def MOUSEOVERnumbers():
    global user_input
    global python_input
    global is_finished

    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        if is_finished:
            user_input = ""
            python_input = ""
            is_finished = False
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()          
        if s_1s.isOver(pos):
            print("1")
            user_input += "1"
            python_input += "1"
        if s_2s.isOver(pos):
            print("2")
            user_input += "2"
            python_input += "2"
        if s_3s.isOver(pos):
            print("3")
            user_input += "3"
            python_input += "3"
        if s_4s.isOver(pos):
            print("4")
            user_input += "4"
            python_input += "4"
        if s_5s.isOver(pos):
            print("5")
            user_input += "5"
            python_input += "5"
        if s_6s.isOver(pos):
            print("6")
            user_input += "6"
            python_input += "6"
        if s_7s.isOver(pos):
            print("7")
            user_input += "7"
            python_input += "7"
        if s_8s.isOver(pos):
            print("8")
            user_input += "8"
            python_input += "8"
        if s_9s.isOver(pos):
            print("9")
            user_input += "9"
            python_input += "9"
        if s_0s.isOver(pos):
            print("0")
            user_input += "0"
            python_input += "0"

# the main loop
run = True
user_input = ""
python_input = ""
is_finished = True

while run:
    # input tap
    inputtap = button((253,100,32),10,280,450,50,f"{user_input}")

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        MOUSEOVERnumbers()

        Symbols()

    redraw(inputtap)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

You then can add a `reset` button to reset the user input. Also after user clicks `=` button, start a new user input rather then concatting on the old one.

The `reset` button is labeled with `C` in this example. Every time user clicks it, empty the user input string and the python input string.

I also use a global `is_finished` boolean variable to check if user clicks `=` button. If user clicks it, it means user has finished the calculation, so that next time user clicks any symbols button, the user input string is cleared.

In the meanwhile, user shouldn't input two sysmbols except `C` button at the same time. I judge it by comparing the last character user inputs and the current character user inputs.

Also, user shouldn't input any symbol before inputting any number. I judge it with global variable `is_finished`. If `is_finished` is true, it means user doesn't start inputting, so there is no value in the user input string. I also use a `IndexError` exception just in case because empty user input string cann't work with negative index.

To distinguish between integer and float result, you can judge if there is dot in the result:

```py
>>> '.' in '45.3'
True
>>> '.' in '453'
False
```

At last, you can also simplify those `if` logic with `button.text` properties like what [Rabbid76](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5577765/rabbid76) does:

```py
        for number_button in numbers:
            if number_button.isOver(pos):
                print(number_button.text)
                user_input += number_button.text
                python_input += number_button.text
```

Comment: could you show me an example how I could make a reset button?

Comment: thank you for taking the time and helping me out! :)

Comment: @HabibIsmail See the updated answer with `button.text` properties learned from another answer. I tried to find that yesterday, but I'm not an expert in pygame and didn't google it out.

Answer (score 3):

Implement a class that can perform arithmetic operations and stores the current text, which has to be displayed (`self.currentText`) on the display:

```py
class Calculate:
    def __init__(self):
        self.currentValue = 0
        self.newNumber = 0
        self.currentOperation = None
        self.currentText = ""
    def newDigit(self, text):
        self.newNumber = self.newNumber * 10 + int(text) 
        self.currentText = str(self.newNumber)
    def newOperation(self, op):
        try:
            if self.currentOperation == '+':
                self.currentValue += self.newNumber
            elif self.currentOperation == '-':
                self.currentValue -= self.newNumber
            elif self.currentOperation == 'x':
                self.currentValue *= self.newNumber
            elif self.currentOperation == '÷':
                self.currentValue /= self.newNumber
            elif self.currentOperation != "=":
                self.currentValue = self.newNumber
        except:
            self.currentValue = 0
        self.currentOperation = op
        self.currentText = str(self.currentValue)
        self.newNumber = 0

calculator = Calculate()
```

Draw the text `self.currentText` in `redraw`

```py
def redraw():
    # [...]

    inputtap.draw(window)
    inputtext = font.render(calculator.currentText, True, (0, 0, 0))
    window.blit(inputtext, (inputtap.x + inputtap.width - inputtext.get_width() - 4, inputtap.y + 4))
```

Invoke `calculator.newDigit` when a digit is pressed:

```py
def MOUSEOVERnumbers():
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        for button in numbers:
            if button.isOver(event.pos):
                print(button.text)  
                calculator.newDigit(button.text)
```

Invoke `calculator.newOperation` when an operation button is pressed:

```py
def Symbols():  
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        for button in symbols:
            if button.isOver(event.pos):
                print(button.text)
                calculator.newOperation(button.text)
        if clearButton.isOver(event.pos):
            calculator = Calculate()
```

---

See the complete example:

[image]

```py
import pygame,math
pygame.init()

window_height = 500
window_width = 500
window  = pygame.display.set_mode((window_height,window_width))

font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 60)

    # the buttons for the shop MENU
class Button():
    def __init__(self, color, x,y,width,height, text=''):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.text = text
        self.over = False
        self.image = font.render(self.text, 1, (0,0,0))

    def draw(self,window,outline=None):
                #Call this method to draw the button on the screen
        if outline:
            pygame.draw.rect(window, outline, (self.x-2,self.y-4,self.width+4,self.height+8),0)
                    
        pygame.draw.rect(window, self.color, (self.x,self.y-2,self.width,self.height+4),0)
                
        if self.text != '':
            w, h = self.image.get_size()
            window.blit(self.image, (self.x + (self.width//2 - w//2), self.y + (self.height//2 - h//2 + 2)))

    def isOver(self, pos):
                #Pos is the mouse position or a tuple of (x,y) coordinates
        if pos[0] > self.x and pos[0] < self.x + self.width:
            if pos[1] > self.y and pos[1] < self.y + self.height:
                return True
                    
        return False

    def playSoundIfMouseIsOver(self, pos, sound):
        if self.isOver(pos):            
            if not self.over:
                beepsound.play()
                self.over = True
        else:
            self.over = False

class Calculate:
    def __init__(self):
        self.currentValue = 0
        self.newNumber = 0
        self.currentOperation = None
        self.currentText = ""
    def newDigit(self, text):
        self.newNumber = self.newNumber * 10 + int(text) 
        self.currentText = str(self.newNumber)
    def newOperation(self, op):
        try:
            if self.currentOperation == '+':
                self.currentValue += self.newNumber
            elif self.currentOperation == '-':
                self.currentValue -= self.newNumber
            elif self.currentOperation == 'x':
                self.currentValue *= self.newNumber
            elif self.currentOperation == '÷':
                self.currentValue /= self.newNumber
            elif self.currentOperation != "=":
                self.currentValue = self.newNumber
        except:
            self.currentValue = 0
        self.currentOperation = op
        self.currentText = str(self.currentValue)
        self.newNumber = 0

calculator = Calculate()
        
                    
white = (255,255,255)
# the numbers for the calcaltor
s_1s = Button((0,255,0),40,450,30,30, '1')
s_2s = Button((0,255,0),40,400,30,30, '2')
s_3s = Button((0,255,0),40,350,30,30, '3')
s_4s = Button((0,255,0),100,450,30,30, '4')
s_5s = Button((0,255,0),100,400,30,30, '5')
s_6s = Button((0,255,0),100,350,30,30, '6')
s_7s = Button((0,255,0),150,450,30,30, '7')
s_8s = Button((0,255,0),150,400,30,30, '8')
s_9s = Button((0,255,0),150,350,30,30, '9')
s_0s = Button((0,255,0),200,450,30,30, '0')

numbers = [s_1s,s_2s,s_3s,s_4s,s_5s,s_6s,s_7s,s_8s,s_9s,s_0s]

# the symbols!
d_1s = Button((0,255,0),260,450,30,30, '+')
d_2s = Button((0,255,0),260,400,30,30, '-')
d_3s = Button((0,255,0),260,350,30,30, 'x')
d_4s = Button((0,255,0),200,400,30,30, '÷')
d_5s = Button((0,255,0),320,450,30,30, '=')

symbols = [d_1s,d_2s,d_3s,d_4s,d_5s]

clearButton = Button((0,255,0),200,350,30,30, 'C')

allButtons = numbers + symbols + [clearButton]

# input tap
inputtap = Button((253,100,32),10,280,450,50,"")

# redraw window
def redraw():
    for button in allButtons:
        button.draw(window)

    inputtap.draw(window)
    inputtext = font.render(calculator.currentText, True, (0, 0, 0))
    window.blit(inputtext, (inputtap.x + inputtap.width - inputtext.get_width() - 4, inputtap.y + 4))
 
def Symbols():  
    global calculator
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        for button in symbols:
            if button.isOver(event.pos):
                print(button.text)
                calculator.newOperation(button.text)
        if clearButton.isOver(event.pos):
            calculator = Calculate()
    
def MOUSEOVERnumbers():
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        for button in numbers:
            if button.isOver(event.pos):
                print(button.text)  
                calculator.newDigit(button.text)

# the main loop
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        MOUSEOVERnumbers()
        Symbols()

    redraw()
    pygame.display.update()
pygmae.quit()
```

Comment: is there a way I could erase all the numbers displayed once it finish calculating because the problem is when you calculate the first 2 numbers and you get your answer and if you trying to calculate againt here is a problem like the numbers will keep adding up look [VIDEO](https://gyazo.com/61d269a7ab851a70dcd868c96a43f35b)

Comment: @Ismael This is is the normal behavior of a calculator. Anyway the "clear" button was missing. I've added it. Of course my solution is very different to the other answer, but I was the goal to present a completely different solution. The first answer to this question is very good and very python like.